# RabbitMQ exchange binding arguments

Tags: rabbitmq

I am setting up bindings from a topic exchange to various queues in RabbitMQ. What does the "Arguments" setting mean on a binding? I cannot find any information in the docs.
[image]
Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 8):

Binding arguments are used for headers exchanges: see https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html for more details.

AFAIK, this is the only case where they are used.

Comment: Weird that they appear when I try to configure a topic exchange then...

Comment: Irrelevant, but I will never understand why you can't specify arguments like `x-message-ttl`, `x-dead-letter-routing-key`, `x-dead-letter-exchange` during `BasicPublish()`. It would have been way more flexible in my opinion.